# The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered (SSIS to populate SQL table from Access source)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS package last week (my first one) using a guide and it parsed correctly and populated my SQL table. I then consulted another guide to create a job to automate the updating of this table but I discovered this morning that this job has been failing. I exported the log and below is the error. Can someone help me pinpoint what the issue is? I think it may be something along the lines of needing to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, but I really don't know. I initially checked the box to run in 32bit runtime, but it failed on that as well as when I tried unchecking it, in case that is important.

> 09/03/2019
>   10:50:14,Update_Equipment_table,Error,1,SERVER,Update_Equipment_table,Update
>   Equipment Table,,Executed as user: SERVER\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R)
>   SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit 
>   Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   10:50:14 AM  Error: 2019-09-03 10:50:15.94     Code: 0xC0209303
>   Source: Package Connection manager
>   "\SERVERPATH\ricochet_tanks.mdb"
>   Description: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is
>   not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed run the
>   package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult:
>   0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error:
>   2019-09-03 10:50:15.94     Code: 0xC001002B     Source: Package
>   Connection manager
>   "\SERVERPATH\ricochet_tanks.mdb"
>   Description: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered
>   on the local machine. For more information see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816  End Error  Error:
>   2019-09-03 10:50:15.94     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task
>   OLE DB Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJwsc.png)     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "\SERVERPATH\ricochet_tanks.mdb"
>   failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
>   call failed.  End Error  Error: 2019-09-03 10:50:15.94     Code:
>   0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description:
>   OLE DB Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. 
>   End Error  Error: 2019-09-03 10:50:15.94     Code: 0xC004700C
>   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more
>   component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2019-09-03 10:50:15.94
>   Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There
>   were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:50:14 AM 
>   Finished: 10:50:15 AM  Elapsed:  1.422 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0

Here is a screenshot of the job details. I believe because I'm using File system as the package source, I have no option to select server credentials or credential type.
[image]

Comment: You probably need the driver installed, but also ensure that the account that runs the jobs has access to the file.  Also that the server has access to the file location

Comment: I added to my post to address your comment. I'm assuming it will affect your suggestion to some degree, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The 64 bit SQL server requires 64 bit ACE driver. If you have the correct driver installed already, need to set the following properties:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1;
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1;
GO
```